# How do I set the date to always read last Saturday in Tableau?

Tags: date, reporting, tableau-api

I do weekly reporting in Tableau and each page is labelled to say data is pulled through every Saturday (Image below).

[image]

My question is if there is a way to program that date to update every week on its own, without having to manually do it for every page on a 52 page report?

I'm not looking to update any data fields, just that label for each page.

Answer (score 1):

See the below link on how you can pull in the last data refresh date:

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/adding-data-refresh-time-stamp-to-view

Or you could have one calculated field that hold this date and add it to every page/view. Then you just have to update one field which will update every view.